# React DataGrid columns show hide

Tags: reactjs

I am using datagrid for my react app (https://js.devexpress.com/). I am able to define columns, add-remove them with column chooser. But I need to add-remove(or show/hide) columns with setState. is it possible? 
Some pseudo-code:

```
`constructor -> 
this.columns =
[
      {
        name: "name",
        title: "Name",
        }, ....
]
<DataGrid
                domain={"manageLocations"}
                columns={this.columns}
                context={context}
                // rows={test_locations}
                dataPath={"locations"}
                getRowId={this.getRowId}
                pagingEnabled={this.pagingEnabled}
                pagingRemote={this.pagingRemote} ......

`
```

The problem is, when I am trying to pass new state to the column, Grid is not updating

Comment: Any code about what you have achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
addColumnsToStore = true; must be false, if you want dynamically add/ remove columns.